# RadioButtonFor and label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using `RadioButtonFor` in my web project, but I want to use the label in order to select the item if the user selects the text of the radio button, but the html generated gives me multiple same #id's because of the Radiobuton and I want to change this in order to have clear html and use jquery selectors without troubles (with the unique id):

CSHTML

```
@foreach (var item in Model.audit.natureSelect)
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.audit.nature, item.Id, new { Value = item.Id }) @item.NatAudit
    </label>
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label><input id="audit_type" name="audit.type" type="radio" value="1">item 1</label> 
    <label><input id="audit_type" name="audit.type" type="radio" value="2">item 2</label> 
    <label><input id="audit_type" name="audit.type" type="radio"value="3">item 3</label>
</div>
```

Thanks to help me to make it clean

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @DoctorMick there is multiple times the same id, this is not correct, the id must be on the dom only once.

Comment: As a side note, your member names are not very C#-y. `Model.audit.natureSelect` should be `Model.Audit.NatureSelect`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the `RadioButtonFor` helper correctly. What you need is for all the radio buttons to have a single name, but different ids. And, here's how you do it:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.audit.natureSelect)
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.audit.nature, item.Id, new { id = item.Id }) @item.NatAudit
    </label>
}
```

By the way, follow C# naming conventions when naming your properties and methods. Property names in C# should start with a capital letter.